# Putting variable as my filename in PHP ignores the full stop

Tags: php

This is probably a simple question but I'm struggling a bit.

```
$filename = $_GET['type'];
$data = file_get_contents($filename.json);
```

When I go to my site www.site.com/report.php?type=1

I get the error:

```
file_get_contents(1json): failed to open
```

Why is it ignoring the full stop to give me a wrong filename (should be 1.json)

Comment: Please configure your PHP error reporting to a value suitable for debugging, so that PHP itself can alert you when you make such beginner’s mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$filename.json` is evaluated by PHP as follows:

- `$filename` is a variable, and evaluates to its contents (`"1"`)
- `.` is the concatenation operator
- `json` is a bareword string, which evaluates as if it was quoted (`"json"`). There is a proposal to remove bareword strings from the language, because they lead to hard-to-track-down errors like this.

When you concatenate `"1"` and `"json"`, you get `1json`.

In order to keep the dot, it must be a string. You can either make use of string interpolation to insert the value of `$filename` into a string, like this: `"$filename.json"`, or you must explicitly concatenate with a string that contains the dot: `$filename . ".json"`.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you concat the string:

```
$data = file_get_contents($filename.".json");
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP will take a dot (.) without quotes as a concatenation sign. but if you will use quotes around the dot like "." it will take this as a string so you should use like following

$filename = $_GET['type'];
$data = file_get_contents($filename.".json");